# In Angular count how many times an image is swiped right

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js for a "tinder like" app. What I'm doing is showing a bunch of images from an array.

Here's a sample of the array:

```
{
  thumbnail: 'images/thor_02.jpg',
  collection: 'Thoroughbred',
},{
  thumbnail: 'images/thor_03.jpg',
  collection: 'Rhapsody',
},{
  thumbnail: 'images/thor_04.jpg',
  collection: 'Chalet',
```

Overall there's 6 in each "collection" and there are 7 collections. I'm showing the images at random. What I need to do is when 4 of the same collection is swiped right, to take them to a new page.

How can I count how many from each individual collection is swiped?

Comment: Are you asking how to detect a swipe right, or just how to count them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to detect a swipe right event, I will answer the question as to how to count the values.

The idea is to keep an object to store the swipes for each collection & direction (if you're interested in keeping lefts vs. rights. If not, you can remove the `left` and `right` properties and simplify your data structure).

The structure would look like the following:

```
swipes = {
  "Thoroughbred": {
    left: 2,
    right: 4
  },
  "Rhapsody": {
    left: 1,
    right: 2
  } // ... you get the idea
}
```

If you didn't care about counting left swipes, you could simplify the data structure like this:

```
swipes = {
  "Thoroughbred": 4,
  "Rhapsody": 2 // ... you get the idea
}
```

Keep in mind this would change the `$this.swipeLeft()` and `$this.swipeRight()` functions in your controller, but that should be easy enough to figure out.

#### DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function() {
    var $this = this;
    var swipes = {};
    var images = [
      {
        thumbnail: 'images/thor_02.jpg',
        collection: 'Thoroughbred',
      },{
        thumbnail: 'images/thor_03.jpg',
        collection: 'Rhapsody',
      },{
        thumbnail: 'images/thor_04.jpg',
        collection: 'Chalet'
      }
    ];
    $this.currentImage = images[0];
    $this.swipeLeft = function() {
      if (swipes[$this.currentImage.collection]) {
        var collection = swipes[$this.currentImage.collection];
        if (collection.left) {
          collection.left += 1;
        } else {
          collection.left = 1;
        }
      } else {
        swipes[$this.currentImage.collection] = {
          left: 1
        };
      }
      $this.currentImage = images[(images.indexOf($this.currentImage) + 1) % images.length];
    };
    $this.swipeRight = function() {
      if (swipes[$this.currentImage.collection]) {
        var collection = swipes[$this.currentImage.collection];
        if (collection.right) {
          collection.right += 1;
        } else {
          collection.right = 1;
        }
      } else {
        swipes[$this.currentImage.collection] = {
          right: 1
        };
      }
      if (collection && collection.right && collection.right >= 4) {
        alert("Collection '" + $this.currentImage.collection + "' has been swiped right 4 times!");
      } else {
        $this.currentImage = images[(images.indexOf($this.currentImage) + 1) % images.length];
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as Main">
  <button ng-click="Main.swipeLeft()">Swipe Left</button>
  <button ng-click="Main.swipeRight()">Swipe Right</button>
  <div class="current-image">
    <h4>Current Image</h4>
    <span ng-bind="'Thumbnail: ' + Main.currentImage.thumbnail"></span>
    <br/>
    <span ng-bind="'Collection: ' + Main.currentImage.collection"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions! Hope this helps!

Comment: I've implemented it and it looks like it's working perfectly. I wasn't thinking to store the swipes as their own object. Brilliant. Thank you very much!!!